# htaccess add page name to url with query string

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am new to this and need some help with an htaccess redirect:

The source URL: http://example.com/?p=1955

Need to convert it to: http://example.com/index.php?p=1955

We recently changed the home page from index.php to index.html and the source URL no longer works. My idea is to check if there is an ?p query string on the url and if so redirect to index.php?p=...

Any ideas on how to accomplish this or other suggestions much appreciated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php [L]
```